# ListView with ODS, BusinessLayer and Dynamic Linq doesn't sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, objectdatasource

Symptoms: ListView not sorting

**Data Layer:** Linq-generated class that includes Northwind Employee table and System.Linq.Dynamic class

**Business Layer:**

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EmployeeData
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int? ReportsToId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EmployeeFilter 
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class EmployeeList
    {
        public int ListCount(EmployeeFilter filter, string sortType, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
        {
            var rows = listQuery();
            return rows.Count();
        }

        public IEnumerable<EmployeeData> List(EmployeeFilter filter, string sortType, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
        {
            var rows = listQuery();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType)) rows = listSort(rows, sortType);
            return (maximumRows > 0)
                ? rows.Distinct().Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows).ToList()
                : rows.Distinct().Skip(startRowIndex).ToList();
        }

        public IQueryable<EmployeeData> listQuery()
        {
            var dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var allrows = from emp in dc.Employees
                          select new EmployeeData()
                          {
                              EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeID,
                              ReportsToId = emp.ReportsTo,
                              FirstName = emp.FirstName,
                              LastName = emp.LastName,
                              Address = emp.Address,
                              City = emp.City,
                              PostalCode = emp.PostalCode,
                              BirthDate = emp.BirthDate,
                              HireDate = emp.HireDate,
                              Title = emp.Title,
                          };
            return allrows;
        }

        public IQueryable<EmployeeData> listSort(IQueryable<EmployeeData> rows, string sortType)
        {
            bool sortDescending = false;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType))
            {
                string[] values = sortType.Split(' ');
                sortType = values[0];
                if (values.Length > 1)
                {
                    sortDescending = (values[1] == "DESC");
                }
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType))
            {
                rows = rows.OrderBy(string.Format("{0}{1}",sortType,(sortDescending) ? " DESC" : ""));
            }

            return rows;
        }
    }
}
```

**User Layer:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstEmployees" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsEmployees" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th align="left">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FirstName">First Name</asp:LinkButton>
                </th>
                <th align="left">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton5" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="LastName">Last Name</asp:LinkButton>
                </th>
                <th align="left">
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton6" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="BirthDate">Birth Date</asp:LinkButton>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("FirstName") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("LastName") %></td>
            <td><%#string.Format("{0:d}", Eval("BirthDate"))%></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        Sorry - no employees found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsEmployees" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectCountMethod="ListCount" SelectMethod="List" SortParameterName="sortType"
    TypeName="BusinessLayer.EmployeeList">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="filter" SessionField="employeeFilter" Type="Object" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="sortType" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="startRowIndex" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="maximumRows" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Analysis:**
I have tested this exhaustively. The sort code is getting called and the query that gets returned from the List method is correctly sorted; however, the data displayed on the form is not sorted.

listSort is returning this SQL query:

```
SELECT [t0].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeId], [t0].[ReportsTo] AS [ReportsToId], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[Title], [t0].[BirthDate], [t0].[HireDate], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[PostalCode]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[BirthDate] DESC
```

**Further testing reveals that I get the same results with a GridView**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that an Object Data Source (ODS) does not do sorting with an IEnumerable. The Linq code must return a DataTable or DataSet. I found two articles that showed how to do that. One was close but incomplete. The other worked like magic: 
[Linq To DataTable](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevesloka/archive/2008/01/28/linq-to-datatable.aspx/%22LINQ%20To%20DataTable%22).

Here is the code that I found and managed to get working in just a few minutes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public static class ConvertDataTable
    {
        public static DataTable ToTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> varlist, CreateRowDelegate<T> fn)
        {

            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            // Could add a check to verify that there is an element 0

            T TopRec = varlist.ElementAt(0);

            // Use reflection to get property names, to create table

            // column names

            PropertyInfo[] oProps =
            ((Type)TopRec.GetType()).GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
            {

                Type colType = pi.PropertyType; if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                {

                    colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                }

                dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
            }

            foreach (T rec in varlist)
            {

                DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow(); foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                {
                    dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
                }
                dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);

            }

            return (dtReturn);
        }

        public delegate object[] CreateRowDelegate<T>(T t);
    }
}
```

And here is the new List method:

```
public DataTable List(EmployeeFilter filter, string sortType, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    var rows = listQuery();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType)) rows = listSort(rows, sortType).Skip(startRowIndex);
    if (maximumRows > 0) rows = rows.Take(maximumRows);
    DataTable dt = rows.ToTable(r => new object[] { rows });
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know how or if a ListView will work with an ODS. I have only used ListViews with an LDS but I do see one possible code issue. If you are expecting one or the other here to fire, you won't get that.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType)) // why repeat the same 'if' statement logic?
{
     string[] values = sortType.Split(' ');
     sortType = values[0];
     if (values.Length > 1)
     {
         sortDescending = (values[1] == "DESC");
     }
}


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortType)) // why repeat the same 'if' statement logic?
{
    rows = rows.OrderBy(string.Format("{0}{1}",sortType,(sortDescending) ? " DESC" : ""));
}
```

Comment: Robinson - there are many examples on the web of using an ODS with a ListView and I have this code working repeatedly in many places... with the one exception of the sorting. listSort is being executed and returning the SQL query that I have added to the code above. Note that the query is correct - it just isn't getting displayed on the web page.

Comment: @Bob, You still have a code issue in your example. That was the main purpose of my answer. You have two identical IF statements with no intervening code. Not following your logic, I wonder if you intend one to fire on false and one on true.

Comment: Thanks, Andy - If you look closely at the code, sortType gets a new value in the first if statement, so the statements are not identical. It can still be tightened though. This code, however, is not the problem. I can now duplicate the issue in both a ListView and a GridView and I suspect that it has something to do with an Object Data Source coupled with a user data class that returns IEnumerable. The research continues.

Comment: Robinson - see the answer below.

Comment: Actually they are above... but you have to love a data source control that is based on almost 10 year old tech that in turn utalizes DataTables which were made almost entirely obsolete with the advent of generics. +1 for being persistent!